# How to make overlapping opaque colors?

Tags: rendering, materials, shaders, compositing-nodes, transparency

I am kinda new to blender, I just want to get the results in the attached image, either with materials (in the viewport) or in the sompositor.
Thanks so much :)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create 3 flat objects, overlap them and give them a *Transparent* node, in Eevee don't forget to choose *Material > Settings > Blend Mode > Alpha Blend*:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134859/discussion-on-answer-by-moonboots-how-to-make-overlapping-opaque-colors).

Comment: @moonboots Thank you so much, I've tried your solution, but I got a black color in the middle, so I added a "Mix Shader" node to the materials and mixed the colored transparent node you've mentioned with a white transparent node and it worked... thank you so much.

https://imgur.com/a/Z3qRtyR

Comment: ok, I don't know what happened but anyway if it works  ;)